# Is there a good demo database for mongodb for play with?

Tags: mongodb

MySQL provides convinient world.db, is there a similar demo database for MongoDB to download?

Answer (score 1):

The [MongoDB learning site](https://university.mongodb.com) offers a lot of (very good) interactive courses to learn MongoDB. Often, courses require to download sample datasets, such as [this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/edu-downloads.10gen.com/M201_2018_April/static/handouts/chapter_3_index_operations.zip) and [this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/edu-downloads.10gen.com/M121_2017_October/static/handouts/chapter_4_core_aggregation_multidimensional_grouping.zip).